# How to reset pandas data reader index?

Tags: pandas, pandas-datareader

I am trying to run this code:

```
from pandas_datareader import data as dreader
from datetime import datetime
ticker = ["SPY","GOOG"]
all_historic_data = pd.DataFrame()



for i in ticker:
  ticker_data = dreader.DataReader(i,'yahoo','1985-01-01',datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d"))
  ticker_data_clean = ticker_data[["Date", "Close", "High", "Low"]]
  ticker_data_clean["date"] = pd.to_datetime(ticker_data_clean["Date"])
  ticker_data_clean.insert(1, "ticker", t)
  ticker_data_clean["return"] = ticker_data_clean["Close"].pct_change()

  ticker_data_clean["range"] = (ticker_data_clean["High"]/ticker_data_clean["Low"])-1
  del ticker_data_clean["High"]
  del ticker_data_clean["Low"]
  ticker_data_clean.dropna(how="any", inplace=True)

print(ticker_data.tail())
```

and getting an error on the 2nd line of the loop

```
> KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call
> last) <ipython-input-51-95844c108758> in <module>()
>       8 for i in ticker:
>       9   ticker_data = dreader.DataReader(i,'yahoo','1985-01-01',datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d"))
> ---> 10   ticker_data_clean = ticker_data[["Date", "Close", "High", "Low"]]
>      11   ticker_data_clean["date"] = pd.to_datetime(ticker_data_clean["Date"])
>      12   ticker_data_clean.insert(1, "ticker", t)
> 
> 3 frames
> /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py in
> _validate_read_indexer(self, key, indexer, axis, raise_missing)    1250             if not(self.name == 'loc' and not raise_missing):   
> 1251                 not_found = list(set(key) - set(ax))
> -> 1252                 raise KeyError("{} not in index".format(not_found))    1253     1254             # we skip the
> warning on Categorical/Interval
> 
> KeyError: "['Date'] not in index"
```

> ticker_data.columns

returns: `Index(['High', 'Low', 'Open', 'Close', 'Volume', 'Adj Close'], dtype='object')`

and

> print(ticker_data.tail())

returns:

```
                  High         Low  ...      Volume   Adj Close
Date                                ...                        
2019-10-09  292.299988  290.059998  ...  62359400.0  291.269989
2019-10-10  294.209991  291.000000  ...  55296300.0  293.239990
2019-10-11  298.739990  296.140015  ...  98720400.0  296.279999
2019-10-14  296.670013  295.570007  ...  40394800.0  295.950012
2019-10-15  299.700012  296.970001  ...  31632183.0  299.239990
```

I could not find a way to remove/reset the Date index 
Pls advice.
Thanks
    [5 rows x 6 columns]

Comment: [`DataFrame.reset_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html)

Comment: tried this and still getting "KeyError: "['Date'] not in index""

Comment: Are you assigning the result back: `ticker_data = ticker_data.reset_index()`?

Comment: ticker_data.reset_index(level=0, inplace=True) - this solved it - the inplace....